# horizontal css/javascript menu - keep showing submenu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, sticky

I am trying to adapt a horizontal css/javascript menu.  Once user clicks on top level menu options, I want lower level options to stay open until user clicks on another link in the menu.  I am using this jquery example as a starting point. 
http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function jsddm_open()
{  jsddm_canceltimer();
   jsddm_close();
   ddmenuitem = $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');}

function jsddm_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function jsddm_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(jsddm_close, timeout);}

function jsddm_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseover', jsddm_open)
   $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)});

document.onclick = jsddm_close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the closing timer.

```
  delete this: //  $('#jsddm > li').bind('mouseout',  jsddm_timer)}); 
  add        : });
```